# Geometry Nodes how to transform extrude based on top and side?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a basic shape which I want to manipulate with geometry nodes.

I want to extrude the faces, and then move the faces down a little. What I would like to have is demonstrated in the image below:

[image]

However, I am not able to move the *side* faces down with the transform function because the transform function does not accept them.
[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Transform* node is for moving geometries as a whole. To reach inside (with a *Selection* socket) and manipulate vertices, edges, and faces, you can use the *Set Position* node instead:

[image]